# How to get the storage key from my 3D floorplan scene id?

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

I upload my 2D flow plan and receive the 3D floor plan mail. I can get the scene id from 3d floor plan url, but I can not use it to my aframe scene since agrane need storage key to load the scene. I can paste the scene id to app creator to get the storage key data. How can I get the .data3d.buffer from my uploaded 3d model through storage API not through app creator?

Comment: we will very soon release our 3d.io scene API within 3dio-js which will give you access to the sceneStructure as well as it let's you convert sceneStructure into aframe elements on the fly.

    io3d.scene.getStructure(<id>)

    io3d.scene.getAframeElements(<id>)

will keep you posted once it has landed

Comment: Update: we released the scene API - see answer below

Comment: Is there a way to do this that works server side and will give you the storageKey directly (as the original question asks) so it can be fed to the model export API?

Answer (score 3):

we just released the scene API with the new 3dio.js version 1.0.1

To get the baked model (data3d.buffer file) including the furniture items from an Archilogic scene into A-Frame you can do:

```
const sceneId = '5dc58829-ecd3-4b33-bdaf-f798b7edecd4'
const sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene')
io3d.scene.getAframeElements(sceneId)
  .then(element => {
    sceneEl.appendChild(element)
  })
```

Take a look at the documentation here: https://3d.io/docs/api/1/scene.html

To improve the A-Frame lighting for interior spaces you can add the `io3d-lighting` component to the A-Frame scene element.

```
<a-scene io3d-lighting>
</a-scene>
```